# Does `get-char-property-and-overlay(nil org-image-overlay)` mean that the first argument was nil or `org-image-overlay`?

Tags: org-mode, debugging, doom, org-link

I've spent over 20 hours trying to solve [an issue](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/org-yt/issues/6) with org-mode loading. I've stepped through the code until it reached a function that stack trace indicates fails due to one of the arguments being `nil`. I'm not familiar enough with emacs debugger to understand which one of the arguments returns nil - is it the result of `(org-element-property :begin el)` evaluation or the `'org-image-overlay' symbol?

This is unrelated to this question, but does anyone know if it's safe to just remove this function? It's adviced as part of org-yt, but it causes a lot of problems.

[image]

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)
  get-char-property-and-overlay(nil org-image-overlay)
  org-display-user-inline-images(nil nil nil nil)
  apply(org-display-user-inline-images (nil nil nil nil))
```